# Get LIMIT from related Tables

Tags: python, django

Got code/

```
context['menu_shop'] = ShopMenu.objects.filter(shop=shop_id)
```

Model:

```
class ShopMenu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Название раздела')
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, verbose_name=u'Заведение',
                         related_name="menushop")

class ShopSubMenu(models.Model):

     name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Название подраздела')
    shopmenu = models.ForeignKey(ShopMenu, verbose_name=u'Надкаталог',
                             related_name="submenushop")
    dish = models.ManyToManyField(Dish, blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % (self.name)

class Dish........
```

Whant create vertical paginator but can't understand how get Dish limit 
So how i can get Dish by LIMIT FROM `ShopMenu`?

\Template:

```
                            {% for menu in menu_shop %}
                          <h2 class="h1_title">{{ menu }}</h2>
              <div class="row row-catalog">
                          {% for submenu in menu.submenushop.all %}

                            {% for dish in submenu.dish.all %}


class Dish(models.Model):

     criterion_list = (
        ('1', u'Блюдо без мяса'),
        ('2', u'Острое блюдо'),
        ('3', u'Здоровое питание'),
        ('4', u'Акция'),
        ('5', u'Блюдо сезона'),
        ('6', u'Блюдо дня'),
        ('7', u'Ваше любимое блюдо'),
        ('8', u'Еда за баллы'))

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Название')
    criterion_first = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,
                                   null=True,
                                   choices=criterion_list,
                                   verbose_name=u'Критерий 1')

    criterion_second = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,
                                    null=True,
                                    choices=criterion_list,
                                    verbose_name=u'Критерий 2')

    price = models.FloatField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Цена',
                          default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Вес',
                          blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=3000,
                               verbose_name=u'Описание',
                               blank=True, null=True)
    points_price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u'Цена за баллы',
                                   default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    is_points = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=u'Еда за баллы',
                                default=False, blank=True)
    is_recom = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=u'В рекомендациях?',
                               default=True, blank=True)
    sale = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u'Скидка',
                           blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=u'Блюдо активно?',
                                default=True, blank=True)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, verbose_name=u'Заведение',
                         related_name="dishshop")
```

yeah sure. that Dish claass need get that it on template by Limit for each sub menu

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the Dish class as well?

Comment: yeah sure. u can seee that in question